# Methanol/water mix freezing point vs specific gravity?

Tags: phase

I need to determine the freezing point of the methanol-water mix in the ground loop of my heat pumps.  I have a hydrometer and have measured the specific gravity as 0.905.  How do I convert this to a freezing point?

The specific gravity was taken at about 16°C (60°F).

I found this [chart](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/methanol-water-d_987.html) for mass and volume, but not specific gravity.

Comment: You need a table of specific gravity vs concentration.

Comment: In case of methanol, the English edition of Wikipedia compiled a [*data page*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol_(data_page)#Properties_of_aqueous_methanol_solutions) including a section *Properties of aqueous methanol solutions:* concentration of methanol by weight or by volume% in water, specific gravity data recorded at different temperatures, and freezing temperatures of these solutions. Is the range of protection (lowest entry for a solution at $\pu{−35.6 C^\circ{}}$) enough for your area?

Comment: @Buttonwood: I'm happy to see the concentration of the methanol/water solution with density of $\pu{0.905 kg/L}$ is about $57\% \ (w/w) $ in both your chart and mine. Thus, I'm confident of my freezing point calculations.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Affirmative, Canadian [Novosolution](http://novosolution.ca/index-en.html) publishes a plot (pdf chart [Freezing Points of Methanol Solutions](http://novosolution.ca/images/Freezing-Points-Methanol.pdf)) equally in vicinity of your results.  Since their business depends on using the correct data, arguably data backed by experience.

Comment: @Buttonwood  Yes, thank you.  Duh.  Not sure why that didn't come up in my searches; I should have just looked that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of interesting question so I have done few searches. According to [this calculations](https://www.handymath.com/cgi-bin/methanoltble3.cgi?submit=Entry), concentration of a methanol/water solution of which has the specific gravity of $0.905$ at about $\pu{16 ^\circ C}$ is roughly $57\% \ (w/w)$ (see density under the $\pu{15.56 ^\circ C}$ temperature column). Then, you can find the freezing point of that solution under [this chart](https://novosolution.ca/images/Freezing-Points-Methanol.pdf). Accordingly, it is approximately $\pu{-63 ^\circ C}$.

When I used the above calculator instead of the chart, I got concentration of $56.6\% \ (w/w)$ which gives the freezing point of $\pu{-62 ^\circ C}$ (not big different for your perspective).