# Does a higher concentration of Methanol to Water increase or decrease heat absorption?

Tags: heat

I have a ground source heat pump with a relatively high concentration of methanol in the ground loop.  See [this post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170680/methanol-water-mix-freezing-point-vs-specific-gravity).

When the system is running, the fluid in the ground loop comes in at about -3.3°C and exits at about -5.6°C.  As answered in the above post, the freezing point of the fluid is about -63°C, well below the operating point.

Will heat transfer be increased or decreased if the methanol concentration is lowered, for example, down to 20%?  Is the difference significant?

I see that the isobaric mass heat capacity at 25°C of methanol is 2.14 and water is 4.18, but I don't know if or how that relates to heat transfer.

Comment: Heat conductivity is probably not an issue if the heat exchanger is properly designed. Higher heat capacity means the substance will take up more heat to reach the T set point. Probably volumetric units would be more useful than specific (mass based), but you can probably assume densities are comparable.

Comment: You have data tables here for mixtures but need to convert it to your volume ratio and to a specific heat capacity: http://www.ddbst.com/en/EED/CPE/CPE0%20Methanol%3BWater.php

Comment: @Buck Thorn  Thanks, way over my head here.  Assuming operating temp of ~-3°C, those tables & graph are all for too high temps.  But the slopes of the curves are about the same, so if I seat-of-the-pants extrapolate to a lower curve for 270°K, the increase in heat capacity for a methanol/water ratio of .2 instead of .5 is about 2 to 3 J/mol*K.  That seems like a lot compared to what it is at 0.5 now; maybe double.  But higher heat capacity is useless if it doesn't transfer due to conductivity limits as a result of time below ground; which I don't have a handle on.

Comment: An educated guess is that if either the mixture or water equilibrate in the loop to the external T then the mixture will reduce the heat transport rate since it will absorb or release less heat on each pass. The difference could be as high as ~30% lower for a 50:50 mixture if the heat capacity is additive (which it might not be). If the liquid does not equilibrate with the external T, the water will absorb even more heat (>~30% difference) - the T difference with the surroundings will be greater with water and Newton's law of cooling says more heat is transmitted for a greater T difference.

Comment: Thanks.  The ground temp is ~7°C, the fluid ~-3°C, so a ΔT of ~10°C.  So not a lot, but not equillibrium and enough to work.